# Django: query group by format year-month-day hour:minute with other columns

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-queryset

I have an Django query . I want to filter data from model- BulkOrder and group by them accordingly partner and pickup_time together. pickup_time is in Datetime format.

Django BulkOrder Model seems like:

```
class BulkOrder(models.Model):
    partner = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    pickup_time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

What have I tried so far

```
from django.db.models import Func

class MonthSqlite(Func):
    function = 'STRFTIME'
    template = '%(function)s("%%y-%%m-%%d %%h:%%m", %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.CharField()
```

I first try to group by data for only pickup_time by using this Django query :

```
BulkOrder.objects.annotate(m = MonthSqlite('pickup_time')).values('m')
```

getting error :

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Want to know How to fix this error  and how to group by data with additional column name partner. or Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: You want to filter BulkOrder by partner and pickup_time?

Comment: yeah by grouping them both , and  group pickup_time  by typeof  according to year-month-day hour:minute

Comment: You can pass multiple parameters in the filter method. BulkOrder.objects.filter(partner="partnername", pickup_time=timeobj)

Comment: i have to group by based on partner and pickup_time , not  filter